# Como a segunda célula da última coluna?

Tags: html, table

Opa galera, blz? Como alinhar essa tabela? Está dando pau aqui o Browser não está reconhecendo que tem 8 linhas, e com isto ele está jogando a segunda célula para a direita.

```
<table class="table" width="100" style="width: 100%!important; border: 1px #ccc solid!important;" border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th rowspan="8">1</th>
    <th rowspan="8">2</th>
    <th rowspan="8">3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
    <th rowspan="2">6</th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
    <th rowspan="2">6</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
    <th rowspan="2">6</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
    <th rowspan="2">6</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O correto é você pular de 2 em 2 linhas (`tr`) para inserir a célula com `rowspan="2"`, porque irá englobar a linha (`th`) em que ela está e a linha posterior:

```html
    <table class="table" width="100" style="width: 100%!important; border: 1px #ccc solid!important;" border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="8">1</th>
        <th rowspan="8">2</th>
        <th rowspan="8">3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th rowspan="2">6</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th rowspan="2">6</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th rowspan="2">6</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th rowspan="2">6</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>
```

Comment: Vlw obrigado. Funcionou filé.